# "Undefined index" notice after submitting HTML form

Tags: php, html, forms

So I have a sign up form, and there is some PHP at the top of the code. It gives me this error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: register in /home/content/04/7195304/html/index.php on line 20
```

This is line 20:

```
if ($_POST['register']) {
```

Here is the submit button:

```
<input type="submit" class="gobutton" value="Register" name="register"/>
```

**Edit**

So here's my form tags:

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
```

Comment: You have not shown us enough code. In particular, you haven't demonstrated your `<form>` tags. Perhaps you're using `GET` not `POST`.

Answer (score 8):

You should check it like this:

```
if ( isset($_POST['register']) ) {}
```

to avoid getting notice.

Comment: -1 If the field is in the right form, and the form method is `POST`, then the variable will be set even if it's empty. I agree that it's wise to use `isset` where you can, but this is not the OP's problem.

Comment: I agree, additionally you should perform !empty() check.

Answer (score 2):

Is your form using method="GET" instead of method="POST"?

You can also add addition checks to make sure the index exists, like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
    // do stuff
}
```

You can also debug the form submission like this:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```